# How to implement a custom DLL I made with Public Subs

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am working on making my own game, and I want to implement a custom DLL that I have made. It uses custom Public Sub arguments, and it seems that I can't implement it properly. The code for the DLL goes like this:

```
Public Class EventChanger
    Public Sub StopEvent()
        'code here to stop event
    End Sub
    Public Sub StartEvent()
        'code here to start event
    End Sub
End Class
```

I compiled it, and added the reference to it, and added the code to it.

```
Imports EventChanger
```

And when I make the code it looks like this:

```
Imports EventChanger
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        EventChanger.EventChanger.StopEvent()
        'other code
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'other code unrelated to event
    End Sub
End Class
```

I get a error like this, so then I tried this:

```
Imports EventChanger

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        EventChanger.StopEvent()
        'other code
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'other code unrelated to event
    End Sub
End Class
```

But I still get an error. Could someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: BC30469  Reference to a Non-shared member required a object reference.

Comment: If EventChanger is a class, you must have an EventChanger instance to call one of its methods i.e. `Dim ec As New EventChanger() ... ec.StartEvent()`. Otherwise, your DLL needs to be a Module

Comment: So should I use a `Public Sub EventChanger`, and then `End Sub` where I need it? Or is it something else?

Comment: @soohoonigan sorry I saw your comment was edited after I posted mine.

Comment: Either you need to create an instance of the class (i.e. an object), and call the methods via that object, as @soohoonigan suggested, or you need to make the methods shared (e.g. `Public Shared Sub StopEvent`).  Which way is more appropriate, in your situation, is impossible for us to say.

Comment: @soohoonigan Do I add `Dim ec As New EventChanger()` in my `EventChanger.dll` file, or do I implement it into my main code?

Comment: @StevenDoggart Thank you, your code help me. It is now working, I will now mark it as resolved.

Comment: If you stick with EventChanger being a class, you would want your EventChanger instance to be declared in your "main code", most likely at the class-scope level. Then within your click events, you would call your EventChanger instance's methods... Although @StevenDoggart made a good point that making the methods static may also solve your problem, so you may want to do some googling about "Shared" and see if it's a good fit for you

Comment: @soohoonigan Thank you for your help, I am still expanding my knowledge on vb.net. I googled looking for answers and could not find what I was looking for. Now that I know to add `Shared` to my code `Public Sub`, I will use that for future use.

Comment: We don't put "Solved" or "Resolved" in the titles here.  If you have it resolved, post the solution as an answer.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: If the entire class is made up of static methods then maybe a Module (static class) would be more appropriate. Also the qualified class name being the same as the namespace looks a little clunky `EventChanger.EventChanger.StopEvent()` don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the code to

```
Public Class EventChanger
    Public Shared Sub StopEvent()
        'code here to stop event
    End Sub
    Public Shared Sub StartEvent()
        'code here to start event
    End Sub
End Class
```

Worked. Now I can do the following code:

```
Imports EventChanger
```

And when I make the code it looks like this:

```
Imports EventChanger
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        EventChanger.EventChanger.StopEvent()
        'other code
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'other code unrelated to event
    End Sub
End Class
```

This works for me.